# About two point Taylor series expansion needs new code

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I wanted to obtain an expansion of some functions around the points x = -1 x = 1 as Zeta (x) 0 with functions that have poles within the interval in question but with the  Lopez/Temme 2002 code gives errors could modify the code to obtain good expansions of these points around two points.

```
   (* Lopez/Temme 2002, eqns. (10),(11) *)
ClearAll[aLT, aLTTerm, twoPtTaylor];
aLT[f_, {z_, z1_, z2_}, 0] := (f /. z -> z2)/(z2 - z1);
aLT[f_,                (* function expression in terms of symbol z *)
   {z_, z1_, z2_},     (* symbol and two points *)
   n_Integer?Positive  (* degree *)
   ] := 
  Sum[((n + k - 1)! *
    ((-1)^(n + 1) n (D[f, {z, n - k}] /. z->z2) + (-1)^k k (D[f, {z, n - k}] /. z->z1))) /
     (k! (n - k)! n! (z1 - z2)^(n + k + 1)),
   {k, 0, n}];
(* Lopez/Temme 2002, eqn. (3) *)
aLTTerm[f_, {z_, z1_, z2_}, n_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 (aLT[f, {z, z1, z2}, n] (z - z1) + aLT[f, {z, z2, z1}, n] (z - z2)) ((z - z1) (z - z2))^n;
twoPtTaylor[f_, {x_, x1_, x2_}, deg_] := Sum[aLTTerm[f, {x, x1, x2}, n], {n, 0, deg}]
```

for example for the function Sin e^x gives good approximation but for $$f(\text{x$\_$})\text{:=}\frac{e^{-x}}{x+1}$$ gives infinite expression 1/0 encountered.and should give$$\frac{z-1}{4 e}+\frac{1}{4} e (z-1)-\frac{e z}{2 (z+1)}+\frac{e}{2 (z+1)}+\frac{z}{2 e (z+1)}+\frac{1}{2 e (z+1)}$$

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.SE]!  If you're asking for modifications to [code from a previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171090/about-two-point-taylor-series-expansion), you should explicitly give credit to the original code by linking to the original question.